# how to add a string to the same string multiple number of times

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Given that there are two inputs- a String and a number.

I wish to append the string with the same .
Eg:

Input:

```
a 10
```

Output:

add a to the String 'a' such that it appears 10 times.

```
aaaaaaaaaa
```

another example:

```
Input:
ab 5

OUTPUT: 
ababababab
```

Comment: Just try the most naive way you can think of, and see if that works or not

Comment: `10 * 'a'` will do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a function like below:

```
In [1389]: def myfunc(string, number):
      ...:     s = string * number
      ...:     return s

In [1391]: string = input("Enter string:")
In [1392]: number = input("Enter number:")
In [1396]: myfunc(string, number)
Out[1396]: 'aaaaaaaaaa'
```

Python multiplies the string to number if given like `'a' * 2`.

Comment: When you provide a technical solution, you need to describe how you came up with your answer. This will help  the original poster and anybody who comes searching.

Comment: Sure. Edited answer to have a proper function to do stuff.

Answer (score 0):

## It will Help You

```
num = int(input()) #for how many times we want to print string
string = input()  # String which we want to print

for i in range(num): # loop will run for num (User Input) times which come from input
    print(string)
```

## if you want to print in a single line

```
print(string , end = " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Think Twice , Code Once

**Simply You can do with using * operator**

```
n = int(input("Enter a number"))
string = input("Enter a String")

print(string*n) # it prints your string n times
```

**With Function**

```
def num_multi(n , s):
    return n*s 


number = int(input("Enter a number"))
string = input("Enter a String")
print(number*string)
```

Answer (score -2):

Python 3.x:

```
def printstring(string,number):

        print(string * number)

        return 


number1 = int(input("Enter here: "))

string1=  input("enter a number")

print(printstring(string1,number1))
```

[image: Show result]

Comment: `IndentationError: expected an indented block`. And that is not how you input to a variable, it gives `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. And you need to convert (cast) `number` to `int` at some point before you multiply by `number` otherwise you get `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'`. And your brackets are not matched on the last line, causing `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. And your function returns `None` which you then print. And why do your lines end in semicolons? Apart from that, great stuff!